# How to correctly assign the ajax response to the dynamically added field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button (`#addNewElement`) that adds an input field and a select dropdown on click. When the input field is changed, it sends an `ajax` request and returns the `options` for the corresponding select box. But the problem is when I change the option of any of the dynamic select options, all other select options also get changed. How can I solve the problem?

I have been looking for the way of correctly assigning the response to the specific dynamic field for a while, but have not got the correct explanation.

```
$("#addNewElement").click(function() {
        $('#addElement').append("<div>\n\
        <label class='form-name'>Element name: </label>\n\
        <input type='text' name='element_name[]' id='element_name' class='eName'>\n\
        </div>\n\
        <div>\n\
        <select name='formulation[]' id='formulation' class='formulation'>\n\
        <option value=''>Select Formulation</option>\n\
        </select>\n\
                </div>");
            $('.eName').on('change', function() { //Am I targeting all the eName?
                if ($(this).val() != '') {
                    var action = 'element_name';
                    var query = $(this).val();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "fetch.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {
                            action: action,
                            query: query
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('.formulation').html(data); //Am I changing all the formualtions?
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```

Before:
[image: Before]

After adding an element and changing its formulation, the first one gets changed too...
[image]

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Well yeah, you are using `.formulation` in the success callback, a class that would be on all of them.

Comment: Can you suggest what should I use instead? Thanks @ggdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the corresponding `select` to the current `input`.

1. Modify your HTML to wrap both the `input` and `select` in one wrapper
2. Use `closest` to get that wrapper and then `find`the `select` inside it (You will have to save `$(this)` in a `var` first)

Basically,

```
$this.closest('.wrapper').find('.formulation')
```

```js
// change here (in HTML structure)
$("#addNewElement").click(function() {
  $('#addElement').append("<div class='wrapper'>\n\
<label class='form-name'>Element name: </label>\n\
<input type='text' name='element_name[]' id='element_name' class='eName'>\n\
<select name='formulation[]' id='formulation' class='formulation'>\n\
<option value=''>Select Formulation</option>\n\
</select>\n\
</div>");
});


$(document).on('change', '.eName', function() { //Am I targeting all the eName?
  // change here 
  var $this = $(this);


  if ($(this).val() != '') {


    // change here (for testing only, will change bgcolor of current select)
    $this.closest('.wrapper').find('.formulation').css('background', 'red');


    var action = 'element_name';
    var query = $(this).val();
    var result = 'formulation'; //Am I targeting all formualtions?
    $.ajax({
      url: "fetch.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        action: action,
        query: query
      },
      success: function(data) {
        // change here 
        $this.closest('.wrapper').find('.formulation').html(data); //Am I changing all the formualtions?
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addNewElement">add</button>
<div id="addElement"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the explanation.  :)